# Remove all small words from string except few

Tags: python, regex, pandas, nlp

I have a text string like following. I want to remove all small words from text till the length of 2 alphabets except a few words

```
st = "PD never failed to be, it is very good"
```

To remove small words till the length of 2 I am using below regex, which is working fine

```
re.sub(r'\b\w{1,2}\b',' ', str(st))
```

But I don't want PD to be removed, as below list words I don't want to delete.

```
list = ['PD', 'CD', 'LD']
```

How can we do this with regex

```
desire result :- "PD never failed  ,     very good"
```

Comment: As usual, with a lookahead, e.g. `\b(?!(?:PD|CD|LD)\b)\w{1,2}\b`. If they all are two-letter words, you may even use a lookbehind.

Comment: Please post this as an answer, Thanks